# actionlink in kendo grid not passing value to controller

Tags: controller, kendo-grid

For some reason this code below is passing a null to the controller. I have used similar code before so i am not sure why this isn't working.

Can i pass a parameter directly from the model like I am doing here? Is it the HtML.Raw that is messing it up?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GiIncidentReportList)
                  .Name("IRGrid")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                  {

                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID)
                          .Template(@<text>@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "WorkflowOverview",
              new { area = "Dailylog" }, new { id = item.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID }).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/Images/icon_edit.gif\" />"))  </text>)
            .Title("").Width(70);






                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport.IR_CaseNumber).Title("Case Number");
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentCreatedByName).Title("Created By");
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport.IR_CreatedDate).Title("Created Date");
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentUpdatedByName).Title("Updated By");
                      columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport.IR_UpdatedDate).Title("Updated Date");
                  }

                  )

            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i got it working.

```
columns.Bound(r => r.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID)
                          .Template(@<text>@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "WorkflowOverview",
              new { area = "Dailylog", id = item.IncidentReport.IR_IncidentID }, null).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/Images/icon_edit.gif\" />"))  </text>)
            .Title("").Width(70);
```